# How to create shortcut files with user-defined "type"?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, file-shortcut

**Default Behavior**
Using the default context menu option's to create a new shortcut file via the OEM wizard, the shortcut "[type](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Au6FcD8kvdA9kSyEmlHz_7J9q7Fm?e=uN8wLK)" is automatically and arbitrarily assigned by the system without any obvious method for user intervention via the frontend UI.  The resultant file may have varying *Property* tabs or fields available, etc, and renaming extension does not reassign the shortcut type to the desired type (e.g., from *.url* to *.lnk*).

**Scope of Use**
An example of why one might need some method to circumvent this behavior -- *preferably* without adding an excessive difference in complexity, time, keystrokes, and/or technical knowledge required -- would be when trying to create a shortcut .lnk that follows a custom protocol/URI(?), e.g., *ms-settings://*; this ends up creating a .url, which will not resolve as desired.  Note: this is just an example, I do realize there are other methods to achieve the intended effect, but this would arguably be considered the most intuitive method which most users would *presume* would work.

**Objective**
Is there any method -- preferably without the use of 3rd party utilities -- to create shortcuts *with* user-defined attributes/properties/etc.?

Comment: By saying "any method", do you include or exclude commandline-based tools that add "excessive difference in keystrokes" etc.?

Comment: @grawity I think `cmd`-based or anything native is fine, I was more referring to 3rd party / external applications by that.